# How to use a state from another file in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a storybook project and created a new custom component. I used a hover state and when I hover the component, it updates its className and it just works fine. Named: ProductSize

And then, I created a new component to group the ProductSize component and named it as ProductSizeGroup and grouped them by the Json inside the ProductSizeGroup stories.

[image]

And here is the final product screen:

[image]

Here, I want to see the sizes when I hover the boxes. But, it shows me all the sizes all alone like this. Apparently, I only want to see XSmall when I hover to XS, Small in S etc..:

[image]

Edit: Many people asked for the coding side and that is here - a live coding example:

https://codesandbox.io/s/usestateissue-10l4l

So, how to solve it?

Here is the `ProductSizeGroup` component code displaying the `ProductSize` items and hover-triggered sizes

```
const ProductSizeGroup: React.FC<IProductSizeGroupProps> = (props) => {
  const { ProductSizes } = props;

  const [inHover, setHover] = useState(false);

  return (
    <Box style={{ width: "100%" }}>
      <Typography>
        {" "}
        Size:
        {ProductSizes.map((products: any) =>
          inHover ? products.name : undefined
        )}
      </Typography>
      <Box display="flex" justifyContent="flex-start" p={1} m={1}>
        {ProductSizes.map((products: any) => (
          <Box
            onMouseEnter={() => setHover(true)}
            onMouseLeave={() => setHover(false)}
          >
            <ProductSize
              inStock={products.inStock}
              sizeText={products.sizeText}
              name={products.name}
            />
          </Box>
        ))}
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Comment: This question seems quite simple and would be solved much more quickly if you simply included the code from your `ProductSizeGroup` into the question

Comment: @Phil I know we can solve it quickly that way. However, the job requires me to do this way :/ So, that's why I need to solve in this way

Comment: The _job_ requires you to not post relevant information to StackOverflow? That's a very strange requirement

Comment: Oh, I already created a codesandbox link and it has a working example and shows the problem clearly :)

https://codesandbox.io/s/usestateissue-10l4l

Comment: You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). To get the best answers to your question we like to see that you've attempted to solve the problem yourself first using a [mcve]. [Here's a question checklist you might find useful.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: There are over 200 lines of codes in total. I am not sure how can I add it, or should I add it. Instead, I put them all inside a working example and I think that makes it a good question.

Comment: All you needed was the code for displaying the sizes and the code for setting `inHover`. All up, about 8 - 10 lines of code

Comment: So, I think that's where I stuck @Phil :( I cannot find a way. Maybe you can help?

Comment: Done. You now have a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) as part of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you're displaying the *size* via the following

```
Size:
{ProductSizes.map((products: any) =>
  inHover ? products.name : undefined
)}
```

where `inHover` is simply a Boolean value. So this will either show all `name` values or nothing.

I think what would work better is something like the following where you set the `hovered` state to the value you want and simply display it

```
const [hovered, setHovered] = useState<string | undefined>();

return (
  <!-- snip -->

  <Typography>Size: {hovered}</Typography>

  <!-- snip -->
  {ProductSizes.map(product => (
    <Box
      onMouseEnter={() => setHovered(product.name)}
      onMouseLeave={() => setHovered(undefined)}
    >
      <!-- etc -->
    </Box>
  ))}
)
```

[image: Edit useStateIssue (forked)]

Take note that I've also removed some of your `any` typings in the sandbox.

Comment: Thank you so much Phil. I do appreciate your solution and it just works great. I definitely try to learn it from your coding :)

Answer (score -2):

In order to handle states, you can use the react context provider: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html or react redux https://react-redux.js.org/.

Depending on how many states you have and what you want to do with them you can choose one of the two. React-redux loads only the states you need, it is faster, but it has a specific structure that you need to follow. It is more complex at the beginning, but you can easier handle multiple states.

Context provider is already installed with react, it is easier to set up, but it is slower since it loads all states on each page load.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your detailed answer. However, the project does not allow me to use Redux :/

Comment: Try then with the context provider. It is already contained in React, you just need to add it in the App.tsx and to add the states. https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html